# messagebox on top of splashscreen

Tags: c#

I have a messagebox that pops-up when a user can't be loaded (in this case because he don't have a warehouse) while loading there is a splashscreen that shows that the data is being loaded. 
I tried the TopMost set to true, but yeah the spalshscreen isn't the parent so it don't work, so i tried TopLevel set to true but it didn't do the trick.

So i tried:

```
MessageBox.Show(Splashscreen.LoadingScreen.ActiveForm, e.Message, "No warehouses", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
```

but this is cross thread so I get an: *InvalidOperationException*
So is there another way to set the messagebox on top?

Comment: Why don't you just close the popup and then open the `MessageBox`?

Comment: What the hell :| Why didn't I tought about that???

Comment: It would be wiser to do so, you don't want to start using `TopMost` everywhere or anything more complicated (`TopMost` is usually buggy and not working as inteded anyway)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this it will show your MessageBox at the top of every window currently open.

```
MessageBox.Show(this,
        "Your text",
        "Settings Needed",
        MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,
        MessageBoxIcon.Question,
        MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1,
        (MessageBoxOptions)0x40000); // this is MB_TOPMOST flag
```

This will keep the message box on top of every window because we are passing `MB_TOPMOST` Value to MessageBoxOptions parameter. You can visit [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee503608.aspx) for more information.

Comment: Nice answer. You'll get my upvote once you add a bit of explanation to it (why does it work and why do we need this curious 0x40000 value?).

Comment: top thanks that did the trick exactly what I wanted, and yust wanted to ask what Heinzi says :P

Comment: @SyedFarjadZiaZaidi: Already checked it, liked it and upvoted it some time ago (4 -> 5). :-)

Comment: (MessageBoxOptions)0x40000 does the same as MessageBoxOptions.ServiceNotification. If not tried, please try and use ServiceNotification instead of hard coded hexadecimal value.

Answer (score 2):

I faced similar issue - my MessageBox get hide behind of SplashScreen. Neither use of "this" adwiced here, nor "new Form" works for my WPF application. However, the construction

```
MessageBox.Show(msg, errType, MessageBoxButton.OK, 
    MessageBoxImage.Asterisk, reply, MessageBoxOptions.ServiceNotification);
```

with ***MessageBoxOptions.ServiceNotification*** helps, putting MessageBox on top of SplashScreen.